# Show G is abelian iff the componentwise product homomorphism condition is satisfied:

Tags: abelian-groups, abstract-algebra

Let $(G, \cdot, e)$ be a group. For homomorphisms $\theta: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$, $\psi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$, define the componentwise product as 
$\theta \cdot \psi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G; n \mapsto \theta(n)\psi(n)$

Show that $G$ is abelian iff the following condition is satisfied:

For all homomorphisms $\theta: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$, $\psi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$, the componentwise product $\theta \cdot \psi$ is also a homomorphism.

For the ($\Rightarrow$) direction, I have, for any homomorphisms $\theta, \psi$ and $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$,
    \begin{align*}
 \theta \cdot \psi (nm) & = \theta(nm)\psi(nm) & \\
 & = \theta(n)\theta(m)\psi(n)\psi(m) & \text{since $\theta, \psi$ are homomorphisms} \\
 & = \theta(n)\psi(n)\theta(m)\psi(m) & \text{since $G$ is abelian}\\
 & = (\theta \cdot \psi(n)) \cdot (\theta \cdot \psi (m)). & 
 \end{align*}

For the ($\Leftarrow$) direction, I don't see why this is true.

I want to show that for any two elements $a,b \in G$, we have $ab = ba$. If I know that $a$ and $b$ are in the image of some homomorphism, then the result follows because we can say that if $a = \theta(n)$ and $b = \psi(m)$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then 
\begin{equation*}
\theta \cdot \psi (nm) = \theta(n)\theta(m)\psi(n)\psi(m) = \theta(n)\psi(n)\theta(m)\psi(m),
\end{equation*}
so $ab = \theta(n)\psi(m) = \psi(m)\theta(n) = ba$.

However, it is not clear to me why any element of $G$ is the in the image of one of our homomorphisms because we don't have surjective homomorphisms.

Can I claim that since we're considering all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$, given an element in $G$, there exists a homomorphism that maps some integer to that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For any two elements $g,h$, there's $\phi,\theta: \Bbb Z\to G$ such that
$$\phi(1)=g,\theta(1)=h.$$

What does it mean that $\phi\cdot\theta(2)=\phi(2)\cdot\theta(2)$?

Comment: $\theta \cdot \phi(2) = \theta \cdot \phi(2\cdot 1) = \theta(2)\theta(1)\phi(2)\phi(1) = \theta(1)\theta(2)\phi(1)\phi(2) = \theta \cdot \phi(1 \cdot 2)

Comment: no, $\theta\cdot\phi(2)=\theta\cdot\phi(1+1)=(\theta\cdot\phi(1))^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I responded before I was done. So, I have $\theta \cdot \phi(2) = \theta(1)\phi(1)\theta(1)\phi(1) = hghg$. Then how do I get to gh = hg?

Comment: $\theta(2)\phi(2)=\theta(1)\phi(1)\theta(1)\phi(1)$. Now translate that into $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Doesn't this just get me $hghg$ again? Sorry, I think I'm confused with the addition. Why doesn't $\theta \cdot \phi(1+1) = \theta \cdot \phi(1) + \theta \cdot \phi(1)$?

Comment: Addition is in $\Bbb Z$. The operation in $G$ is usually written as multiplication $\cdot$ (as given in the question). The right hand side gives you $hghg$, the left hand side should give you something else.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense, thanks. So $\theta(2)\phi(2) = \theta(1+1)\phi(1+1) = \theta(1)\theta(1)\phi(1)\phi(1) = hhgg$. So $hhgg = hghg \Rightarrow hg = gh$.

Answer (score 0):

You are just there.

**Hint:** Consider $n\mapsto g^n$. Is it a homomorphism for each $g\in G$?